# Why are Applicants Often Asked to Draft Their Own Recommendation Letters in Academia

Tags: ethics, application, recommendation-letter, professorship, academic-life

As I know, it's not uncommon for professors to ask students to draft their own recommendation letters in academic settings.

Firstly, I want to know how this impacts the authenticity of the recommendation. Writing one's own letter can be challenging, as it's essential to balance highlighting strengths and achievements without sounding boastful. Moreover, ethical concerns arise when students write their letters, which professors sign off.

What are the reasons behind this practice, and how do institutions view it? Also, how can students and professors collaborate to ensure that these letters are ethical and practical?

Comment: I don't write LORs for graduate admissions, but have for job applications broadly (academic, national lab, industry jobs). At the very least I want to know how the applicant thinks my letter fits into their application, that is, what I should be focusing my comments on compared with other references. If the applicant does not know, well, that is a good starting point for a discussion. Any outlines or drafts I've gotten serve as a reference to make sure I've covered the appropriate points. I've never signed a LOR the applicant drafted.